# Full screen background video

Tags: css, html, video, background

I'm using the HTML5 video element to display a full screen background video on a page:

HTML

```
<video poster="<?= MEDIA_URL ?>images/video-placeholder.jpg" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" preload="">
    <source src="<?= MEDIA_URL ?>video/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="<?= MEDIA_URL ?>video/flower.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="<?= MEDIA_URL ?>video/flower.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

CSS

```
video {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 0;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This works well, except, because the video's 1920 x 1080, on a smaller screen (like my 1440 mac) most of the video is cropped.

Is anyone aware of any other ways to achieve this without cropping so much of the video?

Comment: Try setting the css `width:100%;` and leave `height:auto;`

Comment: @ahmadalbayati This caused a blank space at the top and bottom of the video at certain screen sizes unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

I think so its gonna work.
Or try put tag

```
 video
```

inside a one

```
<div></div>
```

Then change they attributes.

If solve your problem tell me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try background: -webkit-canvas (after you add the video to the canvas) or even better you can use -moz-element...They work of-course only in chrome and firefox so it's probably not what you're looking for but these are 2 ways that it's good to know...You can read about the -webkit-canvas here : http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/12/Canvas-driven-background-images and bout -moz-element here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element.